# Want to change font style in JTextArea by setting an action to a button with StyledEditorKit.BoldAction() method

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

please help... Presently I'm learning Java by my self. My goal is to create a text editor and to have a possibility to change text style of the selected text with StyledEditorKit. I have read How to use StyledEditorKit with JTextArea. Created the JMenu with JMenuItems. Assign the Actions BoldAction and ItalicAction but the text property is not changing. There is something I'm doing wrong... Here is my code

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.text.*;

public class StyledEditorKit_Prueba {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EditorFrame myFrame= new EditorFrame();

        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

 }


}


class EditorFrame extends JFrame{

public EditorFrame(){

    setBounds(500,200,500,350);

    setResizable(false);

    setTitle(" StyledEditorKit Use");

    EditorPanel myPanel= new EditorPanel();

    add(myPanel);

    setVisible(true);

    }
}

class EditorPanel extends JPanel{

public EditorPanel(){

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    miAreaT= new JTextArea();

    add(miAreaT, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//_______________________________________

    JPanel panelBarMenu= new JPanel();

    JMenuBar barMenu= new JMenuBar();

    menu= new JMenu("Change Style");



//___________________________________________________

    JMenuItem bold= new JMenuItem("Bold");

    JMenuItem italic= new JMenuItem("Italic");

    bold.addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.BoldAction());

    italic.addActionListener(new StyledEditorKit.ItalicAction());

//---------------------------------------------------       

    menu.add(bold);

    menu.addSeparator();

    menu.add(italic);

    barMenu.add(menu);

    panelBarMenu.add(barMenu);

    add(panelBarMenu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
//----------------------------------------------------



}

private JTextArea miAreaT;

private JMenu  menu;

}
```

Comment: I thought that these types of editor kits are used in text components that use styled documents, not plain documents as a JTextArea uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JTextArea doesn't support bold or italic text.

You need to use a `JTextPane` to support stylized text.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information and working examples that do what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It Works